# Airflow DAG: Custom Email when Task Fail

Tags: python, airflow

I have 1 DAG including task1>>task2.
This DAG will always run every 15 minutes. Task1 will occasionally fail and because I have on_failure_callback set for this DAG, when task1 fails I will receive a notification. However, I only want it to notify me of an error if this task1 has failed 100 times in a row. Because dag will always rerun after 15 minutes, I don't want to use the `retries` variable.

So is there any way to help me do this? Thank you everyone for taking the time to read this article.